# Any way to organize the "Shared with me" section in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have a lots of shared resources from my studies, and I need most of them.

The problem is that it's hard to follow all the folders and files (not always with an unambiguous name) and remember the references of each of them (course, teacher, year etc.).

**Any way to organize it somehow? folders/labels? Anything!**

---

**EDIT**: I prefer not to copy the files to my Drive, both from storage and keeping the resources up to date perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can add shared files to your own Google Drive and then organize them there however you like. It shouldn't affect how the original owners of the files view their documents because yours is a copy.

Does that work?

Comment: You can also color code folders if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I forgot to mention that I prefer not to copy the files to my Drive, both from storage and keeping the resources up to date perspective. Do you have any extra idea?

Comment: Once I add them to my google drive I can move them back into the "shared with me" section of the drive. However, I can't make new folders in that section. 
It's a very clunky workaround, but if I needed to organize things in my shared folder for work, I could:
1 - Make a folder structure in my personal gmail gdrive
2 - Share it with my work G-drive
3 - Import the shared work files into my work Google Drive
4 - Organize them back into the shared folder structure I created

If that sounds ridiculously complicated it's because google drive's folder handling is pretty terrible.

Comment: Especially compared to something like Dropbox. I'm not sure if the above is helpful to you at all because it's a lot of work just moving files around, but it should get the job done. Someone else might know of a better workaround.